# SQL SERVER 2012 error

Tags: sql-server

am trying to restore a backup, the backup is from a database in the current instance, want to restore the backup with a different name for test purposes, this was possible in 2008 R2 but in 2012 its not possible, anybody know a work around

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It is still possible in 2012. If doing it in the SSMS UI just type the desired new name in the box. If TSQL use `RESTORE DATABASE [NewName] FROM ...`

Comment: the error is that it creates the new database but when its done locks down the existing database and says restoring indefinately

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot(s) of the steps you are performing?

Comment: `RESTORE DATABASE [YourDatabase] WITH RECOVERY;`

Answer (score 1):

You may use t-sql for restore. Make sure that you create new files instead of replacing your existing database.

Try someting like this:

```
    USE [master]
    RESTORE DATABASE [new database name] FROM  
    DISK = N'path to your full backup' WITH  
    MOVE N'logicaldatafilename' TO N'path to your mdf file',  
    MOVE N'logicallogfilename' TO N'path to your ldf file',  
    NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

I hope it helps.
Janos